# Is there any downside to disabling a specialization HQ?

Tags: simcity-2013

If I've already unlocked the upgrades provided by an HQ, is there any reason to keep it on? Can I just shut it off and save on the maintenance and utilities it requires?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of:

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107820/does-demolishing-or-closing-city-hall-upgrades-and-specialization-hqs-affect-the

Comment: I'm mostly interested in local city consequences of disabling the building, not regional ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn it off you will lose the ability to use your special buildings.  This will also happen if you are playing in a shared map, and someone turns off a shared resource.  This happens, for instance, when you have your City Hall built up in a region with say Department of Finance.  If it is turned off, you lose the ability to tax by wealth, and get bonds over 25k.

Comment: Note that, until your exports reach the upgrade limit it is a *good idea* to keep them off.